# Swing: Canvas overlaps menu

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame with a menu bar and a canvas covering all the remaining surface. When I click on the menu bar, the menu opens **behind** the Canvas and I can't see it. Has anyone experienced this? Other than resizing the Canvas (which I am reluctant to do) is there any solution?

Thanks,
Vlad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're experiencing heavyweight vs. lightweight issues.

The quick fix:

```
// Call this sometime before you use your menus 
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)
```

[Heavyweight vs. Lightweight](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/index.html)

Comment: Or use a JComponent instead of a Canvas.

Comment: The JComponent idea was actually saner. I didn't think of looking for a Swing equivalent of Canvas. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

That happened to me when i resized a Canvas that is on a JFrame.
I just had to call

> validate()
>   on the JFrame after the resize.

Good luck!