# ComboBox items are overlapped

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, combobox, vlcj

Please have a view of the attached image.
I use VLCJ to build this application. However, it is unexpected that the item in combobox is hidden by the Canvas (which is used in VLCJ player).  How to solve it?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the jre version the following line may help:

```
 comboBox.setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

which tells swing to use a heavyweight dropdown instead of a lightweight one.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue has been answered here, [Swing: Canvas overlaps menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268750/swing-canvas-overlaps-menu).

**NB:**
*A comment on the answer there is suggesting the use of* `JComponent` *instead of a* `Canvas`. *Consider that.*

Comment: Thank You. But I must use Canvas because it is required for VLCJ api.

Comment: @Bear: The given link suggests the same workaround, anyway. Have you tried to open that?